# Vs code 'c:\Users\Baej\Desktop\2+2=22\Strony\js\script.js'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

recently I tried to run js code in my vs code, but I hit on problem Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\Baej\Desktop\2+2=22\Strony\js\script.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
and couldnt run it. I tried reinstalling vs code and node.js couple times but it didn't work. Now I am not able to run any code in vs code. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your JavaScript code. Seems like you tried to run some fileSystem module command and you got the path wrong because you probably used `./` instead of `${__dirname}` which depends on where you are running your JavaScript file.

Comment: In my js file I had only console.log("text") and It didnt code, I tried to run empty code still didnt work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all node cache files which were in "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache", then I reinstalled VS code and node.js, also removed all VS extensions which were in "C:\Users\user.vscode\extensions", then I installed them all again in vs code and it finally helped. Im closing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).